# Django CMS i18n url problems

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

I'm having 404 problems using **Django CMS 3.0.0.beta3, Django 1.6.1 and i18n**.

When I go to my site, everything is displayed, but when I try to click in the upper bar into Administration or whatever I get a 404 saying:

```
http://my_server/es-es/admin/
```

But instead, this URL is working!!

```
http://my_server/es/admin/
```

I don't understand why this **es-es** string puts itself in the middle. I have tried to change the **LANGUAGE_CODE** to *es* under settings.py but still nothing.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

**Part of settings.py**

```
SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cms',  # django CMS itself
    'mptt',  # utilities for implementing a modified pre-order traversal tree
    'menus',  # helper for model independent hierarchical website navigation
    'south',  # intelligent schema and data migrations
    'sekizai',  # for javascript and css management
    'djangocms_admin_style',  # for the admin skin. You **must** add 'djangocms_admin_style' in the list before 'django.contrib.admin'.
    'django.contrib.messages',  # to enable messages framework (see :ref:`Enable messages <enable-messages>`)
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # The docs say it should be absolute path: PROJECT_PATH is precisely one.
    # Life is wonderful!
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('es', 'Spanish'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

LANGUAGE_CODE should be 'es' and be sure to kill all cookies